# How to join two tables that are joined together with two other tables each

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've been taking my head for a while.
I wish to make a query that joins two tables, each of these tables and joined with two other tables as the schema below.
I know how to join tables but at this point I block.

```
SELECT

 recipe_requirement.ID recipe_requirement_ID,
 recipe_requirement.RecipeID recipe_requirement_RecipeID,
 recipe_requirement.MaterialObjectTypeID,
 recipe_requirement_MaterialObjectTypeID,
 recipe_requirement.Quantity recipe_requirement_Quantity,    
 recipe_requirement.IsRegionItemRequired,
 recipe_requirement_IsRegionItemRequired,
 recipe.ID recipe_ID,
 recipe.Name recipe_Name,
 recipe.StartingToolsID recipe_StartingToolsID,
 items.ID items_ID,
 items.ContainerID items_ContainerID,
 items.ObjectTypeID items_ObjectTypeID,
 items.Quantity items_Quantity,
 items.FeatureID items_FeatureID,
 objects_types.ID objects_types_ID,
 objects_types.Name objects_types_Name,
 movable_objects.ID movable_objects_ID,
 movable_objects.ObjectTypeID movable_objects_ObjectTypeID,
 movable_objects.RootContainerID movable_objects_RootContainerID,
 movable_objects.IsComplete movable_objects_IsComplete,
 movable_objects.CustomNameId movable_objects_CustomNameId

FROM recipe_requirement

JOIN movable_objects ON movable_objects.RootContainerID = items.ContainerID

JOIN objects_types ON objects_types.ID = items.ObjectTypeID

JOIN recipe ON recipe.ID = recipe_requirement.RecipeID

JOIN items ON items.ObjectTypeID = recipe_requirement.MaterialObjectTypeID

JOIN objects_types ON objects_types.ID = Recipe_requirement.MaterialObjectTypeID

WHERE movable_objects.IsComplete = 1
```

Example of table

```
T1 : recipe_requirement 
ID  1708
RecipeID    498
MaterialObjectTypeID    383
Quantity    1
IsRegionItemRequired    0

T2 - recipe 
ID  498
Name    Beef Stew
StartingToolsID 1054

T3 - items  
ID  5780
ContainerID 844
ObjectTypeID    383
Quantity    357
FeatureID   0
```

T1 is linked on T2 with value "498".
T1 is linked on T3 with valude 383".

And in the same time :

```
T3 - items  
ID  5780
ContainerID 844
ObjectTypeID    383
Quantity    357
FeatureID   0

T4 - objects_types  
ID  383
Name    Beef

T5 - movable_objects    
ID  728
ObjectTypeID    104
RootContainerID 844
IsComplete  1
CustomNameId    4
```

T3 is linked on T4 with value "383".
T3 is linked on T5 with value 844".

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error? Is the result set not what you expected it to be? Please edit your question. If necessary, first read: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, how to make this cause i know it is not working.

Comment: Not working how? An error, or an unexpected result?

Comment: To emphasize what the others already said: there's nothing fundamentally wrong with joining all those tables. To answer your question, we need to know two things: What did you get? and What did you want? Along with your query, simple example result sets — one that is what you get, the other what you want — with the fewest number of rows necessary will get you a meaningful answer right quick.

Comment: Hi, i found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Solution i found :

```
`SELECT
    recipe_requirement.ID recipe_requirement_ID,
    recipe_requirement.RecipeID recipe_requirement_RecipeID,
    recipe_requirement.MaterialObjectTypeID recipe_requirement_MaterialObjectTypeID,
    recipe_requirement.Quantity recipe_requirement_Quantity,
    recipe_requirement.IsRegionItemRequired recipe_requirement_IsRegionItemRequired,
    recipe.ID recipe_ID,
    recipe.Name recipe_Name,
    recipe.StartingToolsID recipe_StartingToolsID,
    items.ID items_ID,
    items.ContainerID items_ContainerID,
    items.ObjectTypeID items_ObjectTypeID,
    items.Quantity items_Quantity,
    items.FeatureID items_FeatureID,
    objects_types.ID objects_types_ID,
    objects_types.Name objects_types_Name,
    movable_objects.ID movable_objects_ID,
    movable_objects.ObjectTypeID movable_objects_ObjectTypeID,
    movable_objects.RootContainerID movable_objects_RootContainerID,
    movable_objects.IsComplete movable_objects_IsComplete,
    movable_objects.CustomNameId movable_objects_CustomNameId
FROM recipe_requirement
JOIN recipe ON recipe.ID = recipe_requirement.RecipeID
JOIN (items
JOIN objects_types ON objects_types.ID = items.ObjectTypeID
JOIN movable_objects ON movable_objects.RootContainerID = items.ContainerID
) ON items.ObjectTypeID = recipe_requirement.MaterialObjectTypeID`
```